# Why can I give the ex: line a monitor wedgie?

Tags: ex-mode

Does pulling the ex line up like below serve any purpose?

[image: Pulled the ex line up real high, it reads :echo "hike your pants up high!"]

Comment: I would personally need more information about what you try to achieve, what did you try and what was the result of your try in order to help you :-/

Comment: Not sure if I should worship or hate you for that title.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I took the bar at the very bottom of the screen where the the ex mode line appears and I dragged it towards the heavens.  Similar to how dragging the underwear line towards the heavens creates a wedgie.

And I wondered if this serves any useful purpose; like for instance, adding line breaks to your ex command.

Comment: See `:help cmdheight` I believe

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons.  It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Sorry I'm still reviewing it; now days it takes me some time to get back to it with all of my other duties and responsibilities.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I am still trying to return to the project for which the Monitor Wedge applied.  When I get back to it I'll take another look.

Answer (score 1):

It avoids the [hit-enter-prompt](https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#hit-enter) when issuing a command whose output spans more lines than the `cmdheight` value.

Vim issues the [hit-enter-prompt](https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#hit-enter) when the output of the command exceed the [cmdheight](https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#hit-enter) value.

e.g.:

```
set cmdheight=1
echo "foo\nbar"
```

The `echo` command output spans on two lines but `cmdheight` is set to 1. Vim will show the two lines temporarily but will prompt the user with `Press ENTER or type command to continue` before restoring the command height to its `cmdheight` size.

e.g.:

```
set cmdheight=2
echo "foo\nbar"
```

In this example Vim doesn't prompt the user with the hit enter prompt since the output of the command fit within the `cmdheight` value (2 lines in this case)